# How to read most recent Microsoft Outlook 2016 message using AppleScript

Tags: outlook, applescript

How can I display the contents of the most recent message in Outlook 2016 for Mac using AppleScript?

I can do something like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
   return unread count of messages
end tell
```

but I get an error:

```
error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t get unread count of every message." number -1728 from unread count of every message
```

That was my start but I don't know what to do from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.  It writes the most recent message content to "first-message-content.txt"

```
on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try

        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string

        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission

        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0

        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof

        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true

        -- Handle a write error
    on error

        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessage to first item of (get current messages)
    get subject of theMessage
    set theContent to (content of theMessage)
end tell

set theFile to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & "first-message-content.txt")
writeTextToFile(theContent, theFile, true)
```

You can find all the operations of Outlook 2016 by opening the Apple Script Editor, and then choose File > Open Dictionary > Microsoft Outlook.